# Where can I find a code example for using the refresh token to get a new access token?

Tags: api, connected-apps

I am building a connected app.

I have read that I can use the refresh_token to get a new access_token (and thus stay logged in for a long time).

Can anyone point me toward some code samples (in Java or Ruby or Python or Javascript or Clojure) that shows how this call is made?

Comment: Did you already obtain and store the Refresh Token in your app for the Salesforce user using one of the OAuth flows that provides a refresh token?

Comment: Have you read [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en) yet? They describe all the parameters you need to use; assuming you know how to open a HTTP connection with a given endpoint, you should already be most of the way there.

Comment: An additional Salesforce article that provides a great walk-through and a lot of info: [Digging Deeper into OAuth 2.0 on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is the refresh logic](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit/blob/master/forcetk.js#L97) from [ForceTK](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-JavaScript-REST-Toolkit), simplified slightly to make the flow more clear. As noted in the comments above, the Refresh flow is very straightforward:

```
/**
 * Refresh the access token.
 * @param callback function to call on success
 * @param error function to call on failure
 */
forcetk.Client.prototype.refreshAccessToken = function (callback, error) {
    'use strict';
    var that = this,
        url = this.loginUrl + '/services/oauth2/token';
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: 'grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=' + this.clientId + 
              '&refresh_token=' + this.refreshToken,
        success: callback,
        error: error,
        dataType: "json"
    });
};
```

Assuming your callback accepts the parameter `oauthResponse`, you'll get the access token in `oauthResponse.access_token`.